# Can I insert *.gmake to makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

There is a Makefile in which I want to include "a.gmake", can I insert a.gmake's content to this Makefile ?

Comment: Using GNU Make, I suppose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just include your gmake file like

```
include a.gmake
```

as `gmake` is a subset of `make`.
you can find a description of this command [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html).